# How to visualize Apdex score on Kibana?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an Elasticsearch+Logstash+Kibana stack running and would like to visualize the Apdex score for my website.

I am writing a Python script that gets the response times from the apache logs and calculates the [apdex score](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/apdex/apdex-measuring-user-satisfaction#score), but I can't quite figure out how to send this data to Kibana or visualize it on Kibana. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Something tells me I wouldn't even need a script and I should be able to do it with simple querying, but again can't really wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

While parsing the apache logs, you can add an appdex component per each document stored in elastic. You can base the score on whatever condition you want to implement for your apdex calculation.

In kibana, you just display the average of this value in a time-series graph which will server as your apdex graph.

Comment: Well, this suggestion would work only if Apdex was a single field, where I can do some aggregations on the field and pass it on to Kibana. But if you look at the link I provided, you'll understand how Apdex score is calculated and is not as easy to as it sounds.

Comment: So it is done like this - If response_time <= threshold then mark it as 'Satisfied' request, Else if response_time > 4 x Threshold then mark it as 'Tolerating'. After that use the formula to calculate Apdex score, then pass this value. Also there is an overhead of allowing the client to change the threshold value on the go, which is not possible if all the calculation is done in logstash.

Comment: @InquisitiveTech, you did not provide any link. For the apdex calculations that I do, I normally have a constat target time(say 5 secs) which makes it easier for us to calculate at a row level. Do you have a moving target for your apdex score ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've added the link now to the original post. I would have a minimum threshold time as well, but the client is still in the process of figuring out a good threshold value and wants to play around with it until they find a close match. Also they want to filter based on the url to figure out apdex scores for individual pages on the go, just like how it works on new relic.

Comment: do you have the response time per each response in the logs ?

Comment: Yes, of course. And I use them to plot a response time on a histogram graph.